# count objects in a loop

Tags: c++

Here is what I wrote:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 

struct vetura{
    char ngjyra[10];
    char tipi[10];
};

int main(){
    int i,j;
    vetura v[4];

    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        cout << "Ngjyra:"<<endl;
        cin >> v[i].ngjyra;
        cout << "tipi:"<<endl;
        cin >> v[i].tipi;
    }
    j=0;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
        if(v[i].ngjyra == "kuqe" && v[i].tipi == "passat")
        j+1;
    }
    cout<<"kemi "<<j<<" vetura passat me ngjyre te kuqe";


    cin.get();cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I need to count how many times I have wrote "kuqe" for v[i].ngjyra and "passat" for v[i].tipi together. I thought the variable j is going to get bigger everytime it counts but it is not working and I am going to have an exam in the following hours can anyone help me?

Comment: Using character arrays in C++ will do you little good. Use `std::string` unless you have a good reason otherwise. Seeing as how using `==` to compare strings is natural, you might as well use something that behaves correctly with it.

Comment: @chris I am not allowed to use std::string! :(

Comment: Then I am afraid you'll have to use `std::strcmp` to compare the character arrays. `==` won't do what you think it does.

Comment: anything else? because I have a really stupid professor, even he doesnt know what he wants! but I cant use another library! so there is no other way to compare those arrays with a string?

Comment: @TooCooL, `strcmp` works fine. It's just much easier on you using `std::string`. It helps to know C-style strings in the case you have to manipulate them from existing code, or are required to use them in the first place, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two problems:

**First:**

Change:

```
    j+1;
```

to:

```
    j = j+1;
```

Or simpler:

```
    j++;
```

**Second:**

`v[i].ngjyra == "kuqe"` will never be true.  You are checking whether the **location** of `v[i].ngjyra` is the same as the **location** of `"kuqe"`.  And it isn't.

If you want to test whether the character strings have the same value, change:

```
v[i].ngjyra == "kuqe"
```

to:

```
strcmp( v[i].ngjyra, "kuqe" ) == 0
```

Comment: I had it j++ then I changed to j+1, now I tried j = j+1 but the result is always 0!

Comment: It's 0 because your condition is never true.  See Chris's comment on your original question.

Comment: I cant change them because the assignment requires it to be:
char ngjyra[10];
char tipi[10];